# ibm cf git deploy stage invalid app name format

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, devops

I'm using git to push code to my app on cf .
I can build the app. but when I'm at the deploy stage.
I keep getting app name is invalid format.

below is the error log.

```
Downloading artifacts...DOWNLOAD SUCCESSFUL
Target: https://api.ng.bluemix.net
Using manifest file /home/pipeline/992ac343-b17e-4565-9209-c5b28602fd41/manifest.yml

Creating app æˆ‘çš„ä¸ªäººåšå®¢ in org ***@outlook.com / space dev as ***@outlook.com...
FAILED
Server error, status code: 400, error code: 100001, message: The app is invalid: name format

Finished: FAILED
```

I change the app name to ANCI name.but still got the same error.

below is the manifest.yml

```
applications:
- path: .
  memory: 512M
  instances: 1
  domain: mybluemix.net
  name: myblog
  host: blog
  disk_quota: 1024M
  buildpack: python_buildpack
```

Comment: What is the cf push command that you are using? Please share the content of manifest.yml too

Comment: @UmbertoManganiello  I dont' think it's related with manifest.yml, but see the update.

Comment: @UmbertoManganiello the error says invalid name format .when the app is create I use a unicode name..I guess that's the problem

Comment: @UmbertoManganiello I did not use any push command.It's a automatic pipeline when I use git to push code to jazzhub, it's automaticly build and deploy..

Comment: If my understanding is correct you are using the delivery pipeline in DevOps Services. Can you double check your deploy stage configuration  (Build&Deploy->Deploy stage->Settings->Configure Stage)? What is the name of your application?

Comment: @UmbertoManganiello, I found the appname in the Configure Stage is unchanged, even though I changed the name of the app.  Change the app name in the Configure Stage works..thanks the help..

Comment: You're welcome! I'll post it as an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the Delivery Pipeline in IBM DevOps Services, you can check your Deploy stage configuration going to Build & Deploy -> Deploy stage -> Settings -> Configure Stage. Double check that the name of your application there matches the real application name.